# Uses of the copy module (over just making a new variable) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

Say I had code like this:

```
class Animals:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Woah')
    def Eat(self):
        print('yum')
```

And then you made an animals Gilberto:
    gilberto = Animals()

And then you wanted to make another animal named Elijah. Why would you use the copy module:

```
elijah = copy.copy(gilberto)
```

When you could just do:

```
elijah = gilberto
```

Is there anything special about the copy module? In the case of the Animals class, it seems the same.

Comment: `elijah = gilberto` does not make a new variable!

Comment: oops... but why would you use the copy module?

Comment: Because you want a copy.

Comment: yeah, I see now

Comment: @StephenRauch: It does make a new variable, but that's usually pretty useless without a new object.

Comment: @user2357112, is that new variable or a new name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) you're creating a new object, instead of referencing the same object (which is what you're doing in the last snippet).

Consider this:

**Setting up**

```
import copy
class Animals:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Woah')
    def Eat(self):
        print('yum')

gilberto = Animals()
elijah_copy = copy.copy(gilberto)
elijah_reference = gilberto
```

**In the interpreter**

```
>>> id(gilberto) == id(elijah_copy) # Different objects!
False

>>> id(gilberto) == id(elijah_reference) # It's the same object!
True
```

So if I were to, for example, define a new attribute in `elijah_reference` it would be available in `gilberto` also, but not in `elijah_copy`:

```
elijah_reference.color = 'red'
```

**In the interpreter**

```
>>> gilberto.color
'red'

>>> elijah_copy.color
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Animals' object has no attribute 'color'
```

Comment: That's almost correct. elijah = gilberto is assigning two references to the same object (I'm guessing that's what you meant, but your vocabulary wasn't exactly right).

Comment: There's a few more implications that I didn't cover: for example, if I were to `del gilberto`, the object would persist and not get garbage collected, since there's still a reference to it.

Comment: Elijah would change, yes, because they're the same object (look at my example with `.color`, it would work the same way). Side note: if you're adding other objects to your `class`, like a `list`, and you would like to avoid this behavior, consider using a [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: The object is the `list`, `gilberto` and `elijah` are just a reference to it (none of them are the object itself). One object can have as many references as one needs and when you call a function on a reference you'd always be modifying the same object.